# Azure Easy Apis InvokeApi Method is calling GET instead of POST

Tags: android, azure, xamarin.android, azure-api-apps

I am currently working on creating a custom authentication for a Xamarin.Android app using Azure. I have successfully created my API and it is properly returning values when submitting a raw payload using Advanced REST Client.

I am now trying to implement this on Xamarin.Android using Azure's MobileServiceClient SDK and when using the invokeApi method as demonstrated below in my code, I am getting an exception indicating that it is calling GET instead of POST. Is anyone aware of what I might be doing wrong?

ex.Message returns

"Cannot GET /api/register?username=azureAccountTest&password=testingpassword"

```
    public async Task RegisterAsync()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> user = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "username", username },
            { "password", password }
        };
        try
        {
            CancellationToken ct;
            var result = await client.InvokeApiAsync("register", HttpMethod.Post, user, ct);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            var message = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I tested this issue on my local side and I could retrieve the `authenticationToken` as follows:

[image]

You used the following method for `InvokeApiAsync`:

```
public Task<JToken> InvokeApiAsync(string apiName, HttpMethod method, IDictionary<string, string> parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
```

**Note:** It summarizes that the Additional data will sent to through the query string.

Per my understanding, you could refer to the following method for sending additional data though the HTTP content as follows:

```
JObject user = new JObject();
user.Add("username", "bruce");
user.Add("password", "123456");
var result = await App.MobileService.InvokeApiAsync("/.auth/login/custom", HttpMethod.Post, user, ct);
```

Additionally, you need to specific the `mobileAppUri` with https endpoint when deploy to azure side. Here is a similar issue, you could refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45032255/azure-app-service-custom-authentication-http-verb-not-allowed/45047404#45047404). Moreover, I would recommend you refer to adrian hall's book about [Custom Authentication](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/custom/).

**UPDATE:**

Based on your comment, I checked the custom authentication and found the following note from adrian hall's book about [Custom Authentication](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/custom/):

> You must **turn on Authentication / Authorization** in your App Service. Set the **Action to take when request is not authenticated** to **Allow Request (no action)** and **do not configure any of the supported authentication providers**.

Comment: I've actually discovered something new just now through testing, and it looks like my code does work when Authentication/Authorization is disabled on my Azure portal. I am able to retrieve an auth token and user object. This leads me to believe that the problem lies with how my api is routed. I noticed that you routed your custom login to /.auth/custom/login but mine is routed to /api/register so I will try changing that and testing to see if that solves the issue I am having.

Comment: Have you solved this issue, do you need further assistance ?

Comment: I am still trying to solve it, I have since then switched from Node.js to C# for back-end but it seems like Authorization/Authentication has to be disabled for POST requests. So I may just leave it that way for now.

Comment: I checked adrian hall's book and updated my answer with the related note. You are right, disable the Authentication/Authorization or follow adrian hall's instruction for using custom authentication.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Noobie mistake, didn't realize I didn't set up my MobileServiceClient with HTTPS. Changing it from http ://appurl.azurewebsites.net to https ://appurl.azurewebsites.net solved my issue.