# Turning on Azure Mobile Service Authentication results in "Resource does not support GET" on a POST Request

Tags: azure, authentication, jwt, azure-mobile-services

I tried to implement custom Authentication via a authentication endpoint in an azure mobile app. I've created an Api Controller, that creates the Jwt using Azures AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken method. When I post to this controller with turned off Azure App Service Authentication, I get a token, but when I want to use it later, I always receive a "401 Unauthorized".

But when I turn the setting on in the Azure Portal, and send the very same request
I get:

```
The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.
```

I'm not changing any code, and I'm certainly using a POST request - The exact same request, that works with turned off App Service Authentication.

My Code is essentially the same as here:
https://www.newventuresoftware.com/blog/custom-authentication-with-azure-mobile-apps

Could someone enlighten me here? Do I need additional configuration somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As adrian hall's book about [Custom Authentication](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/custom/) states as follows:

> You must turn on Authentication / Authorization in your App Service. Set the **Action to take when request is not authenticated** to **Allow Request (no action)** and **do not configure any of the supported authentication providers**.

For custom authentication, you need to turn on the **Authentication / Authorization** in your app service for authenticating your token. Moreover, I would recommend you leverage [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the network traces to narrow this issue. Additionally, you need to make sure that you send the custom login request with **HTTPS**. Details, you could follow this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45032255/azure-app-service-custom-authentication-http-verb-not-allowed/45047404#45047404).

Comment: Thank you very much, changing HTTP to HTTPS did it... If only I got an error like "HTTP request not allowed to this resource. Use HTTPS instead"... But that would have been too easy, wouldn't it?